# scalajs-react ComponentScope unification

Tags: scala, reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

I have some state-modifying tasks needed to be run inside `componentDidMount` as well inside button click handlers defined in `renderS` method.
Tasks have a lot of common code so i've decided to join them inside one class, that receives scope and applies necessary actions.

Trouble is: inside `renderS` method i have access to `ComponentScopeU[...]` and inside `componentDidMount` i have `ComponentScopeM[...]`

I've found that to access `.props` i need to verify my scope have supertrait `ComponentScope_P[...]`, to access `.state` my scope should have supertrait `ComponentScope_S[...]` and to have ability to `.modState` i should pass implicitly `CompStateAccess[...]`.

So currently i have code like this

```
case class State(...)
type ScopePS = ComponentScope_P[Int] with ComponentScope_S[State]
type StateAccess[C] = CompStateAccess[C, State]
implicit class MyActions[T <: ScopePS : StateAccess](scope: T) {...}
```

It's working but i wonder how could this be simplified, i.e. how could props\state be accessed inside `renderS` and `componentDidMount` via common code?

Comment: This looks like pre 0.10 scalajs-react. Is the same problem present today?